# logger.isDebugEnabled() is killing my code coverage. I'm planning to exclude it while running cobertura

Tags: slf4j, cobertura, buildr

I tried by adding in org.slf4j.* in  cobertura.exclude. but there is no use.
my buildfile

```
require 'buildr/java/cobertura'
require 'buildr/scala'
require 'buildr/myProject'
.....
.....
compile.options.other = %w(-encoding UTF-8)
cobertura.exclude= 'org.slf4j.*'
.....
.....
```

Please suggest how to proceed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `cobertura.exclude` is to exclude files/classes in your project from being instrumented.

What you want to use is `cobertura.ignore`, e.g.,

```
cobertura.ignore 'java.util.logging.*'
```

which accepts a regular expression of class/method name to ignore.

From the Ant task documentation at https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference:

> You can tell Cobertura to ignore certain classes by passing in
>   "ignore" regular expressions. The ignore pattern can be any valid perl
>   5 regular expression. This will ignore any calls to any method that
>   matches the ignore regular expression. It will NOT skip over these
>   classes during instrumention. To exclude classes from being
>   instrumented, either exclude them from your fileset or use the
>   alternative method below and specify an excludeClasses pattern.

Comment: is there similar alternative for jacoco. I tried to exclude log4j classes in jacoco filter but no luck.