# Jacoco coverage report, exclude methods from coverage

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using gradle with and jacoco plugin to collect test coverage. Although we are writing tests for equals and hashcode but I still want to exclude these from test coverage report.
I tried to find this online, but no luck unfortunately..

Could someone please help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I add an annotation to exclude a method from a jacoco code coverage report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re)

Answer (score -2):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29887805/2003986)

Here is an example :

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['somepackage/**'])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for exclusions at method level.