# Java code coverage with jacoco - exclude methods in classes

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

In case of jacoco - we can skip packages which should not be considered for code coverage.
I want to exclude some methods from Java class, not the whole class.
Can we specify specific  which can be excluded?

If yes, where and what configuration changes are required.

I don't want to add annotations on the methods which needs to be excluded. Is there any way to configure. Like if we list down all the methods in 1 file and while executing code coverage, read that file via some configuration and exclude those methods. Is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I add an annotation to exclude a method from a jacoco code coverage report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re)

Comment: I don't want to add annotations on the methods which needs to be excluded. Is there any way to configure. Like if we list down all the methods in 1 file and while executing code coverage, read that file via some configuration and exclude those methods. Is this possible ?

Comment: From the mentioned answer - "Only whole classes can be excluded."