# what is the use of @Generated Lombok annotation

Tags: lombok

In my project codebase, I see `@Generated` annotation being used in many places. When I read through the docs it states the following.

> Lombok will eventually automatically add this annotation to all
> generated constructors, methods, fields, and types.

As per the docs, `@Generated` annotation is automatically added by Lombok for the generated code. Apart from that, `@Generated` doesn't generate any code like `@Getter` or `@Setter` does. I don't see the rationale in using this.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not really sure, but maybe it specifies that the targets will be generated automatically and not provided explicitly.

Comment: As the documentation states, it is for you to know that this is a lombok generated method/field/etc. This helps the IDE to identify the generated classes and warn you from modifying them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I came across one valid use case for `@Generated`. So I thought I will update here hoping it might help someone sometime.

In our project, we use Jacoco to generate a coverage report. There are a few classes and methods that don't make sense to be a part of the coverage report. Eg: configuration classes, POJOs, close() etc.

Classes can be excluded from the report by using the `<exclude>` tag in POM.xml. But If you would like to ignore only one method from a class, you can't achieve that by adding entries in pom.xml.

In scenarios like that, we can use @Generated annotation on methods to be excluded from the coverage report. Cheers.

Comment: Does anybody has a custom annotation to achieve this? It's kinda an overkill using lombok just to exclude classes from Jacoco

Comment: I've found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918619/3001897. And you can change FUNCTION with CLASS to convert it to class level annotation

Comment: Please don't follow this answer. This annotation means "Lombok has generated this class / method", and this just so happens to exclude it from test code coverage because testing auto-generated classes is undesirable. It doesn't mean "this is user code that I don't want to be included in test coverage metrics." If you _really_ want functionality like this, then at least use the answer linked above where you create a custom annotation with a clear purpose.