# jacoco showing filtered code in the coverage report

Tags: java, jacoco

I have added a filter via annotation to exclude a method from jacoco coverage as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918619).

But when I see the jacoco html report for coverage I see the filtered method being shown in red as not covered. Please check the attached screenshot. Is this expected?

[image]

Annotation code looks like below

```
package com.spotnana.common;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport {}
```

Jacoco Version - 0.8.8

Comment: `@ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport` got commented?

Comment: Sorry updated the question. I added a wrong screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [jacoco mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/jacoco/c/0vIt3uDfgco).

> Ok. In this case what you see is the code of the lambda body.
> Technically the compiler creates a method for it which is not
> excluded. I’m afraid this is a limitation of the @Generated
> annotation.

`get()` method is excluded. But compiler internally created a method for lambda which is shown in red in the class level report. This seems to be a limitation of the jacoco `@Generated` annotation.