# How to exclude a specific method from Jacoco scan?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco

My code is not generated and I only want to exclude a specific method from Jacoco scan. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I add an annotation to exclude a method from a jacoco code coverage report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re)