# Ignore coverage function in Jetbrains Intellij not working

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, intellij-idea, annotations, test-coverage

I have a back end application in Kotlin that communicates with the Slack API but these methods are really annoying to test, if it's even possible...

So I want Intellij to ignore them from the coverage, I have created a custom annotation to use:

`@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION) @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE) annotation class IgnoreCoverage()`

And this is how I implement is:

`@IgnoreCoverage
fun start() {

```
    Thread {
        SocketModeApp(app).start()
    }.start()

}`
```

And under settings/build, Execution, Deployment/Coverage I have added the annotation to the 'Exclude annotations' under 'Java Coverage' but somehow it still includes all the Slack call methods in the test coverage

Comment: I've tried this by following the guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824761/how-would-i-add-an-annotation-to-exclude-a-method-from-a-jacoco-code-coverage-re, and it works. Can you share a sample project of that on Google Drive or GitHub? What's the IDEA version you are using?