# Exclude generated Hibernate methods from Jacoco coverage report

Tags: hibernate, jacoco

I would like to exclude methods generated by Hibernate from Jacoco code coverage reports.

For example, the `$$_hibernate_*` methods in the image should be excluded.
[image: Jacoco code coverage report]

I'm aware that to exclude by method the method can be annotated with an annotation that contains the string `Generated` as is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918619/1308634), but I'm not sure how I would apply such an annotation to a Hibernate method.  Maybe I should use the Hibernate [Metamodel Generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#generator) some how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excludes configuration option in your build tool (e.g., Maven or Gradle) to specify which classes or methods should be excluded from coverage analysis.

Here's how you can do it in Maven's pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*$$_hibernate_*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

- `<exclude>**/*$$_hibernate_*</exclude>` specifies that any method or
  class name containing `$$_hibernate_` should be excluded from coverage
  analysis.

Comment: Are you sure that this should work for methods?  I believe that this will only work for classes and packages.  I believe that methods can only be excluded with a `Generated` annotation.  I tried this plugin configuration and it doesn't seem to work.